# Is there a VIM absolute (registers, marks, undo history, tags) bar or tree toggle?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is there a VIM absolute (registers, marks, undo history, tags) bar or tree toggle ?

I mean, like the tag-bar, but with subsections. Having the primary sections to be the followings, custom marks, custom registers, custom records, undo history (as the Gundo plug-in). So undo the bar, we can go to a mark, execute a record, yank or paste a register, etc.....

If there is not, would anyone like to help me build it??? Or just, help me with good starting tutorials for vim plug-in building, since it'll be the first one that I'll make.

Comment: You may try to split your windows and open individual plugins in each pane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's nothing like that, what would be the point of such a monster?

Aren't `:marks`, `:registers`, `:changes`, `:undolist`… enough?

Anyway, you should start by getting familiar with Vim's built-in documentation: `:help eval` contains all the *raw* info you will need.

Steve Losh's [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) is a really great third party ressource and the [Vim Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki) can be useful, too.

Answer (score 2):

Though plugins like *tagbar* and *Gundo* efficiently display information in a side bar, like IDEs, this is mostly a concession to what today's users are used to, but not a fundamental way to use vi(m). Marks and registers are meant to be memorized by their names (`a`..`z`), with the `:marks`, `:registers`, etc. commands to provide you a refresher after a long break / the next day.

There are many plugins (e.g. for automatic mark management and visualization), but I would recommend to use them sparingly. It's definitely a "smell" if you want to turn Vim into a full-blown IDE. Please don't.